# cakephp 2.0 before filter

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, before-filter, cakephp-model

In CakePHP 2.0 version, I have written something like this in `UsersController.php`

```
public function  beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

Here, what `parent::beforeFilter();` will do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It performs the parent's beforeFilter() method. In this case, since `UsersController extends AppController`, it uses AppController's (if existent).

https://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php

Comment: @lakum4stackof: and you should never forget that. its one the most common mistakes and grounds for errors in the code :)